# How to save a NaiveBayes Classifier in Java ML?

Tags: java, serialization, machine-learning, data-modeling, naivebayes

So, I am trying to figure out how to save a Naive Bayes builtclassifier with a given data set. I have tried to serialize it so I can save it but it says it is not serializable. I have tried the java.io.Serializable class and it does not help. I looked at the documentation and it implements the serializable interface. When ever I run the program I get this error: java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.javaml.classification.bayes.Functions. I have been working on this for awhile and was hoping some one could help.

Thank you, John Doe

Comment: What does saving the classifier mean in this case?  Where are you saving it to?  Would it not be sufficient to keep a build or version number with the data and have the source code in an SCM tool like Subversion, Mercurial or Git?

Comment: I want to save the classifier which has been trained by the data to a model( when you build a classifier with a specific method such as Naive bayes you are training a Naive Bayes Classifier. The trained classifieir is what I want to save to my hard drive). Then when I get new data whether I can either predict the results based on my model or further train the model with the new data. I am saving it to my hard drive. And I do not want the data with classifier, I want it to stand by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look into json serialize methods, something like this.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(A,NaiveBayesClassifier.class);
String jsonString = gson.toJson(A);
//A.print();
//Write JSON String to file        
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(IO.Comp_Name() + location + ".ser");
fileWriter.write(jsonString);
fileWriter.close();
```